# Running a task periodically with a cancellation token called from another method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to run a screenshot task every x amount of minutes, but it seems that when i want to cancel that task using the given cancellation token, it doesn't seem to do anything.

Here is my start method code:

```
var CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        CancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();

        CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var token = CancellationTokenSource.Token;
        await RunPeriodically(async () =>
        {

            var screenCaptured = TakeScreenshot();

            if (screenCaptured == null || CancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;

            var correctUserName = Settings.Default.Username.Split('.');
            var parsedUsername = correctUserName[0] + " " + correctUserName[1];
            await ScreenshotHelper.UploadScreenshotAsync(ProjectName, "screenshotscontainer",
                screenCaptured.ToArray(), Environment.MachineName, parsedUsername);
            Console.WriteLine("Took Screenshot: " + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), token);
```

and here is the run periodically code:

```
public async Task RunPeriodically(Action action, TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            action();
            await Task.Delay(interval, token);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You call an `async` `Action` without `await` in your `RunPeriodically` method. And `async void` is a generally bad decision. Redesign it.

Comment: I can't see why it's not cancelling, but I see some other problems: Note that the `action()` call _returns_ when you `await` the upload. So it maybe called more often than you think. And `while(true)` does not take care of the `CancellationToken` (though `Task.Delay` should throw a `TaskCancelledException` afaik).

Comment: At what point are you actually cancelling the task? You create a new `CancellationTokenSource` and never cancel it after that fact.

Comment: I would also recommend using System.Threading.Timer. This will pull a thread from the thread pool and avoid blocking a thread.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd knock up a quick example of a class that will run a process, wait a period of time and start the process again without blocking any threads.

```
class RepeatableProcess
{
    private Timer  processTimer;
    private int delay;
    private CancellationTokenSource source;
    private CancellationToken token;
    private Action processToRun;
    private bool canStart = true;


    public RepeatableProcess(int delaySeconds,Action process)
    {
        delay = delaySeconds;
        processToRun = process;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (canStart)
        {
            canStart = false;
            source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            token = source.Token;
            processTimer = new Timer(TimedProcess, token, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
            processTimer.Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);
        }

    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        source.Cancel();
    }

    public void TimedProcess(object state)
    {

        CancellationToken ct = (CancellationToken)state;
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timer Stopped");
            processTimer.Dispose();
            canStart = true;
        }
        else
        {
            processToRun.Invoke();
            processTimer.Change(delay, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }

}
```

The Start method creates a timer that never starts and never repeats.
It then starts the process immediately, to run only once.

The TimedProcess method checks for cancellation and runs the specified process . After the process completes the timer is set to start after the specified delay and run only once.

When the timer fires it gets a thread from the thread pool. There can be no overrun issues because the timer is not set to run again until the process is finished.

This class would need more protection but it is just an example.
Hope this helps.